# Conditional inference trees in party package R: how to predict the model and variance importance based on OOB data?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I use `cforest` of the `party` package in R to calculate conditional inference trees. Similarly to Random Forest, I would like to retrieve variance explained and the variance importance based on the `OOB` data (I read that Random Forest returns variance explained and variable importance based on OOB data). To do so with `cforest` I used the following code:

```
model <- party::cforest(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 , data=trainings_set ,  control=cforest_unbiased(ntree=1000, minsplit=25 , minbucket=8 , mtry=4))
model.pred <- predict(model, type="response" , OOB=TRUE)
R2=1 - sum((trainings_set$y-model.pred)^2)/sum((trainings_set$y-mean(trainings_set$y))^2)
varimp_model=party::varimp(model, conditional = TRUE, threshold = 0.2, OOB = TRUE)
```

I am interested in whether the command `OOB=TRUE` would lead to the model being predicted and variable importance being returned based on the `OOB data` of the trainings_set?

I posted this question before under a different title, posting it again (slightly redrafted), I hope someone might be able to provide an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `OOB` parameter in `cforest` function is for `a logical defining out-of-bag predictions`.

This is only `TRUE` when you pass a `newdata` parameter in `cforest` which is generally a test data frame. If the `newdata` parameter is there and you have set `OOB=TRUE`, then you will get `out-of-bag predictions` on this `newdata`.

I hope this clarifies your doubt.